# Use Date constructor invocation in serialized json from SignalR hub

Tags: serialization, json.net, signalr

In our project, we use following custom JsonConverter for DateTime:

```c#
public class JavaScriptDateTimeConverter: JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof (DateTime);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {

        var dateTime = (DateTime)value;
        writer.WriteStartConstructor("Date");
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Year);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Month - 1);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Day);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Hour);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Minute);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Second);
        writer.WriteValue(dateTime.Millisecond);
        writer.WriteEndConstructor();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

So, I want to use this converter in SignalR.
Here is my Startup class:

```c#
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
        jsonSerializer.Converters.Add(new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof (JsonSerializer), () => jsonSerializer);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

But when server sends some JSON with date field to client, then client is disconnected with following messages:

> SignalR: Stopping connection.
>   SignalR: Closing the WebSocket.
>   SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.
>   SignalR: Stopping the monitoring of the keep alive.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Without knowing SignalR, I could imagine that the value to be serialized may be `null` (a `DateTime?`) and you get exceptions in your `WriteJson` when trying to access `Year` etc. of the `null` value.

Comment: In this case, I get the exception in line with cast to DateTime, but I test this code with DateTime, not DateTime? I've just corrected my question.